# How to import python library in C++ using Java Native Interface - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, python, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to import the python library into an existing project which uses the JNI. What we are trying to achieve is to call a python script from the JNI source written in C++.

Therefore we did try to include the python library (Python.h), which can't be found without the proper setup.

The Android.mk exists already and I know we could include it there, but then again a shared object of the python library would be needed, right?

This is what I would write into the makefile Android.mk if we would have a shared object:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Include libpython2.7.so
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := python2.7
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../python-for-android/dist/default/libs/armeabi/libpython2.7.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research we finally did it, hopefully this will help someone to get along faster:
We switched from the default Android NDK to [CrystaX NDK 10](https://www.crystax.net/) which has libpython2.7.so already compiled for each arch needed. Then we adjusted our Android.mk to look like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
CRYSTAX_PATH := /home/user/crystax-ndk-10.3.2

...

# Build libpyjni.so (pyjni.c may be an project source file you wrote)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := pyjni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := pyjni.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += python2.7 crystax
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog                
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Include libpython2.7.so
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := python2.7
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(CRYSTAX_PATH)/sources/python/2.7/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libpython2.7.so
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := crystax
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -I $(CRYSTAX_PATH)/sources/python/2.7/include/python/
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Include libcrystax.so (needed by python library)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := crystax
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(NDK_PATH)/sources/crystax/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcrystax.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -I $(NDK_PATH)/sources/crystax/include/
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Afterwards we could build the project in Android Studio.